# KendoUI Date Time Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

We want to disable the possibility of the user to select date or time before `Date.now()`.

Any advice how we can achieve this on KendoUI DateTimePicker please?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#enddatetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
            format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
            parseFormats: ["dd/MM/yyyy", "HH:mm"],
            min: ??????,
            dateInput: true
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript new Date() is already the current date, dont need the now()

```
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
    parseFormats: ["dd/MM/yyyy", "HH:mm"],
    min: new Date(),
    dateInput: true
});
```

Dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/@sehaxx/UmuJIQud

Comment: strange, I tested it already and didn't worked. I'll double check - thank you very much for your response and the clarification.

Comment: https://dojo.telerik.com/@sehaxx/UmuJIQud here is a working dojo, you can test it.

Comment: it worked,  thanks!! (perhaps some cache was the issue)